# how to properly enable open-uri in rails console and therefore get it work in a project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, open-uri

When I require open-uri in rails console by : require 'open-uri'
I get false.
Any suggestions, ideas please ?

Env :
Rails 4.2.4
ruby 2.2.1p85

Comment: While I don't know the answer, this link: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4149-strange-require-behavior-in-development-environment might have some more information for you.

Answer (score 2):

You get false because **the gem is already been loaded**. Rails console load your environment.

```
bin/rails c  
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.alpha)
2.2.3 :001 > require 'open-uri'
 => false
```

If you try require it in a interactive ruby console (irb), the require command return true because the gem has not yet been loaded.

```
irb
2.2.3 :001 > require 'open-uri'
 => true 
# If you try to require it a second time you'll get false because is already been loaded
2.2.3 :002 > require 'open-uri'
 => false
```

Answer (score 2):

Open Uri is by default required in rails console. you can test it by calling `open('http://google.com')` if it runs successfull you already have 'open-uri'